# Only allow PR author or admin to merge to protected master branch

Tags: github, branch, pull-request, access-control

Github allows you to set the master branch as a protected branch. Our work flow is as follows, work on feature branches, merging back to staging. Once happy on staging and we want to create a release, we create a PR from staging to master. Before merging, we request a review by all contributors to the PR. Our process is to wait until all contributors have reviewed before merging.

However, it is possible for anyone on the team to merge the branch before all reviewers have signed off. Is there a feature to do one of the following:

1. Require all contributors to review the release before allowing merge? (And in the case someone is on holiday, allow an admin to override this and merge anyway).
2. Only allow the PR author, or an admin the ability to merge the PR.

Basically, we want to remove the possibility of someone accidentally merging a release to master before everyone has reviewed their contribution (while accounting for people being on leave).

Comment: https://github.blog/2018-03-23-require-multiple-reviewers/? But _"wait until all contributors have reviewed"_ sounds like a disastrously inefficient process overall.

Comment: Can't you configure a list of users with access to the branch?

Comment: @jonrsharpe for now while the team is relatively small it's not too inefficient. The process is mainly so prevent a merge to master before contributors have verified their work on staging is safe. The contributors are only responsible for verifying their own work is safe. Not others. We have code review when merging to staging for that purpose.

Comment: @dan1st you can, however we want all devs to be able to create a release. Just want to put limits on who/when the merge button is clicked.